# Does VS 2015 rename the database after it gets accessed from VS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I created a database in my SSMS 2012 and the path is set to my app_data folder in VS.

After I connect to it in VS and go back to it the database has been renamed and in all caps.These are localdb files.

For example. I name something aaaa. 
After I access that database in VS and look in SSMS it is now named `C:\FOLDER\FOLDER\APP_DATA\AAAA.MDF`.

I am using VS 2015.

Comment: I think you're referring to the file extension and not the name of the file.

Comment: The mdf file itself does not change in the folder however in SSMS it is now called the new all caps extension for some reason.

Comment: Basically in SSMS it got renamed to the file extension